# How can i make this python function better?

Tags: python

Im currently creating a function that will allow to give the highest integer that the user will input.

code:

```
def max_num(x,y,z):

    if x>=y and x>=z:
       return x
    elif y>=x and y>=z:
       return y
    else:
       return z

num1= input("1st value: ")

num2= input("2nd value: ")

num3= input("3rd value: ")

print("The highest integer is:",max_num(num1,num2,num3))
```

when i tried inputting the values 300,1000,200 it always returned 300 its obvious that it should be 1000. anyone have a solution?

Comment: 1000 > 300 but '1000' < '300'

Comment: Yes, convert those strings to integers.

Comment: `input` returns strings. And you're comparing those. Not the integer that they represent

Comment: How about `max((num1, num2, num3))`?

Answer (score 2):

```
num1= int(input("1st value: "))
num2= int(input("2nd value: "))
num3= int(input("3rd value: "))

print("The highest integer is:",max_num(num1,num2,num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings into integers:

```
def max_num(x,y,z):

    if int(x)>=int(y) and int(x)>=int(z):
       return x
    elif int(y)>=int(x) and int(y)>=int(z):
       return y
    else:
       return z

num1= input("1st value: ")

num2= input("2nd value: ")

num3= input("3rd value: ")

print("The highest integer is:",max_num(num1,num2,num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

just use predifined the max() funtion:

```
num1= input("1st value: ")

num2= input("2nd value: ")

num3= input("3rd value: ")

print("The highest integer is:",max(int(num1),int(num2),int(num3)))
```

Comment: `max('300', '1000')` -> `'300'`m, also, the exercise might be to create a user defined `max` instead of simply finding the max value.  It's best to point out the root issue instead of offering a solution they might not need.

Comment: noticed the mistake, edited

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the max function

```
def max_num(x,y,z):
      return (max(x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_num(*args):
    highestNum = 0
    for num in args:
        if num > highestNum:
            highestNum = num
            print("higher num has been found " + str(highestNum))
        else:
            print(str(num) + " is not higher than " + str(highestNum))

max_num(2,3,10,1)
```

output

```
higher num has been found 2
higher num has been found 3
higher num has been found 10
1 is not higher than 10
```